# jQuery UI Sortable update database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Hey I'm working on a CMS for a website I'm building and in the CMS I have all my fields with the data and I'm using jQuery UI Sortable so I can sort them, what I'm wondering is what is the best way to update the order field in my database when I drop my element? Would I use Ajax? If so what should I search to do this function (I've never used Ajax). Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is a great alternative to do just that.

jQuery has built-in support for Ajax.  I would start out with simple examples from the [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and work up from there.

You can use the `change` event of Sortable to know when you need to save the sort order again:

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change